# In postgres, how would I replace or add a prefix/suffix to all the selected text in a column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using DBeaver on a postgres database and I'd like to edit some text from a column.

[image]

From table 'user', column 'name', I have selected the entries named 'James' and 'Bond'.

```
SELECT * FROM public."user" WHERE name IN ('James', 'Bond')
```

What is a good query to add a '007' prefix to these two entries so 'James' and 'Bond' become '007James' and '007Bond' respectively?

Also, after I update the names to show as '007James' and '007Bond', how can I replace the prefix and change those entries to '008James' and '008Bond'?

Thank you

Comment: Use string concatenation `||` as in: `SELECT '007' || name FROM public."user" WHERE name IN ('James', 'Bond') `

Comment: No, I want to ADD '007' to both of these strings.

Answer (score 3):

first part of your question would be like this:

```
UPDATE public."user" SET name = '007' || name WHERE name IN ('James', 'Bond');
```

So, concatenate `007` with current `name` value

For second part, use `REPLACE` function

```
UPDATE public."user" SET name = REPLACE(name, '007', '008');
```